# (Uniform) continuity of a nonlinear function on a locally convex topological vector space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $E_1$ be a (nontrivial) vector space, $P$ be a family of seminorms on $E_1$, $\tau_1$ denote the topology generated by $P$, $(E_2,\tau_2)$ be a topological space, $f:E_1\to E_2$ at $x\in E_1$.

> Can we show that $f$ is $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$-continuous at $x$ if and only if $f$ is $(p,\tau_2)$-continuous for all $p\in P$?

### **EDIT**: If not, is the proof in the reference below wrong or is there anything special in that situation?

The following instance of this setting (found in Linde's *Probability in Banach Spaces*) is confusing me:

[image]
[image]

In his proof, the author has found a single $K$ for which $\hat\mu$ is (uniformly) $p_K$-continuous.

Translated to the general setting in this question, this seems to indicate that it's sufficient to have $(p,\tau_2)$-continuity for a single $p\in P$. Is this really true?

On the other hand, if I got it right, he has even shown *uniform* continuity. Is this the crucial ingredient?

Comment: Good question. It's been ages since I last saw this stuff but I would totally bet that uniformity is key here.

Comment: I tried something, but I can't conclude. For that I should review my functional analysis and I would love so, but I haven't time right now. Let me write down what I have been thinking. I would like to prove that $\hat\mu$ is continuous at $0$, then it would presumably be easy to conclude that it is continuous everywhere. So we need to prove that, for all $\epsilon>0$, the set $$\{a'\in E'\, :\, \lvert \hat\mu(a')-1\rvert<\epsilon \}$$ is an open neighborhood of the origin of $(E', \tau_c(E', E))$. [...]

Comment: A basis of neighborhoods of the origin is given by $$N_{a_1, \ldots, a_n;\delta}=\{ a'\in E'\ :\ \max_{a_1,\ldots , a_n} \lvert \langle a', a_j\rangle \rvert <\delta\}.$$Now I really think that the condition they find in the excerpt you posted suffices to prove that the set of my previous comment contains a set of this kind.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for sharing your thoughts. At the moment, I don't see that it is easier to show continuity at $0$. Please take a look at the question I've asked for that particular problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3879201/47771.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I think I was able to prove the claim; hopefully I did no mistake: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3955938/47771.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one direction is true.

If $f$ is $(p,\tau_2)$-continuous for *any* $p \in P$, then $f$ is $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$-continuous. This follows simply from the fact that $\tau_1$ is finer (larger) than the topology of $p$.

The other direction is not true in general. Let $p,q$ be two nonequivalent norms on a vector space $E$. W.l.o.g. assume that there is no constant $M>0$ such that $p \le Mq$. Let $\tau_1$ be the topology generated by $P=\{p,q\}$ and $\tau_2$ the standard topology on $\Bbb{R}$. Then $p : E \to \Bbb{R}$ is $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$-continuous but not $(q,\tau_2)$ continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, that is what I expected, but what am I missing then in the cited proof of the reference? Is the proof wrong or is there anything special in the situation?

Comment: Please take a look at the answer I've provided to the question whether or not the argument in the cited excerpt is correct: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3955938/47771. Would be great if you could share what you think about it.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I may be missing something, but doesn't the proof use the direction which does hold? It concludes that $\hat{\mu}$ is $(p_K,\tau_2)$-continuous so it is $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$-continuous.

Comment: Are you referring to my proof in the other question? And did you intend to write "the direction wich does **not** hold"? In any case, please take note of the latest edit of my answer and please let me know if you still have doubts.

Comment: @0xbadf00d No, I was referring to the proof in the screenshot in this question. No, I meant the direction which **does** hold.

Comment: You have shown that if $f$ is $(p,\tau_2)$-continuous for all $p\in P$, then $f$ is $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$-continuous. Can we conversely show that if $f$ is $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$-continuous, then $f$ is $(p,\tau_2)$-continuous for **some** $p\in P$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d No, consider my example with $P = \{p,q\}$ where $p,q$ are two *non-comparable* norms. Then $f : E \to \Bbb{R}$ given by $f = p+q$ is $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$-continuous but not $(p,\tau_2)$ nor $(q,\tau_2)$-continuous.

Comment: You're right, but do you agree that the claim is true when $P$ is the family of seminorms generating the topology of compact convergence on $C(X,Y)$ for a topological space $X$ and a normed space $Y$? It should be true: If $(Z,d)$ is a metric space, $f\in C(X,Y)$ and $F:C(X,Y)\to Z$ is $(P,d)$-continuous at $f$, then for each fixed $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $n\in\mathbb N$, compact $K_1,\ldots,K_n\subseteq X$ and $\delta>0$ with $$d(F(f),F(g))<\varepsilon\;\;\;\text{for all }g\in f+\delta\bigcap_{i=1}^nU_{p_{K_i}}\tag1,$$

Comment: where $U_{p_{K_i}}$ is the closed unit ball with respect to the seminorm $$p_{K_i}(g):=\sup_{x\in K_i}\left\|f(x)\right\|_Y\;\;\;\text{for }g\in C(X,Y).$$ Now, $$K:=\bigcup_{i=1}^nK_i$$ is compact as well and it's easy to see that $$U_{p_k}=\bigcap_{i=1}^nU_{p_{K_i}}\tag2.$$ Thus, $F$ is $(p_K,d)$-continuous at $f$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I don't think it holds. Your compact set $K$ depends on $\varepsilon$, you should pick a compact set $K \subseteq X$ such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $g \in C(X,Y)$ holds $$p_K(f-g) < \delta \implies d(F(f),F(g)) < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: @0xbadf00d I believe I have a counterexample. Take something like $F : C_b(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R}) \to \Bbb{R}$ given by $$F(f) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2^n}f(n)$$
where $C_b(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$ is the space of all bounded functions $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ endowed with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets (induced by seminorms $P$). Then $F$ can be seen to be $P$-continuous by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem but for any fixed compact set $K \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ it isn't $p_K$-continuous as you cannot control what happens outside $K$ and $K$ is bounded.

Comment: Now $F$ is a continuous linear functional on a subspace $C_b(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$ of a locally convex space $C(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$ so by Hahn-Banach it extends to a continuous functional $F' : C(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R}) \to \Bbb{R}$ which again isn't $p_K$-continuous for any fixed $K$.

Comment: I know that $K$ depends on $\varepsilon$. What I've shown is that if $f\in C(X,Y)$ and $F$ is $(P,d)$-continuous at $f$, then $$\forall\varepsilon>0:\exists K\subseteq X\text{ compact}:\exists\delta>0:\forall g\in f+\delta U_{p_K}:d(F(f),F(g))<\varepsilon\tag3.$$ And that does precisely imply what I previously claimed: If $F$ is $(P,d)$-continuous at $f$, then $F$ is $(p_K,d)$-continuous for *some* compact $K\subseteq X$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @0xbadf00d No, this **doesn't** imply that $F$ is $(p_K,d)$-continuous. You need $$\exists K \subseteq X \text{ compact} : \forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists \delta > 0 : \forall g \in f + \delta U_{p_K} : d(F(f),F(g)) < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: You're right. However, what I've shown should yield that $F$ being $(P,d)$-continuous at $f$ is equivalent to $(3)$. Do you agree?